# Coldfusion - Loop over columns on a row

Tags: sql, arrays, coldfusion

I have a `CFQuery` which returns some counts.
For example:

```
count1 | count2 | count3
   1   |   23   |  27
```

The result is always one row BUT the columns are not always the same. I mean sometimes might return 3 columns and sometimes 10+ columns which I don't know their names.
My goal here is to loop over the names of the columns and get their values and present them in a table.

I  have tried this:

```
<cfloop list="#qGetCommentsDetails#" index="col">
    <cfloop query="qGetCommentsDetails">
        #qGetCommentsDetails.[col][currentRow]#
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

but I get this error:

> A CFML variable name cannot end with a "." character.
>
> The variable qGetCommentsDetails. ends with a "." character.
>   You must either provide an additional structure key or delete the
>   "." character.

Anyone knows how to loop over columns and their values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing dot notation with bracket notation.

This should do what you want:

```
<cfif qGetCommentsDetails.recordCount>
    <cfloop list="#qGetCommentsDetails.columnList#" index="col">
        <cfoutput>
            #col# : #qGetCommentsDetails[col][1]# <br/>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

The `columnList` attribute is always included in a query object, and is a comma delimited list of the column names. Just use this in your loop and use bracket notation to output the query values.

EDIT: As @Tomalak noted, you can also use `currentRow`:

```
<cfoutput query="qGetCommentsDetails">
    <cfloop list="#qGetCommentsDetails.columnList#" index="col">
        #qGetCommentsDetails[col][qGetCommentsDetails.currentRow]#
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The column name is the `col` variable (`index="col"`) and the value is `#qGetCommentsDetails[col][1]#`, which refers to the query `qGetCommentsDetails` column `col` on row 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer to display the column name as well as the value.

Comment: Using `currentRow` in place of `1` is actually more correct.

Comment: @Tomalak since I'm not using the `query` attribute on  `cfoutput` then `currentRow` would be undefined. Also, since the question stated the query always returns 1 row, then I thought it more appropriate to explicitly say I was using row 1. Otherwise, yes, I would use `currentRow`.

Comment: `qGetCommentsDetails.CurrentRow`, of course.

Comment: Ah! Yes. True. I still hold to my opinion that it's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: If you have only one record, yes. If you are in a query loop, not really.

Comment: I agree. I've updated my answer to show both ways.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Tomalak (copy/paste & forgot to remove superfluous cfoutput) and the discussion.